# JQ getting incorrect output for nested arrays

Tags: json, jq

I'm trying to use JQ to convert a json file into a csv file. I've managed to do this for the file, but during testing I've found the output is not as expected. Please could you help as I've spent hours and hours trying to fix it but can't seem to get there.

Ideally I'd also like to combine the users and groups into one, but I can live without that.

This is a cut down version of my json file.

```
[
  {
    "id": 319,
    "policyItems": [
      {
        "accesses": [
          {
            "type": "consume",
            "isAllowed": true
          },
          {
            "type": "create",
            "isAllowed": true
          }
        ],
        "users": [
          "foo"
        ],
        "groups": []
      },
      {
        "accesses": [
          {
            "type": "publish",
            "isAllowed": true
          },
          {
            "type": "create",
            "isAllowed": true
          }
        ],
        "users": [],
        "groups": [
          "bar"
        ]
      }
    ]
  },
  {
    "id": 320,
    "policyItems": [
      {
        "accesses": [
          {
            "type": "publish",
            "isAllowed": true
          },
          {
            "type": "create",
            "isAllowed": true
          }
        ],
        "users": [
          "foo"
        ],
        "groups": []
      },
      {
        "accesses": [
          {
            "type": "consume",
            "isAllowed": true
          },
          {
            "type": "create",
            "isAllowed": true
          }
        ],
        "users": [],
        "groups": [
          "bar"
        ]
      }
    ]
    }
]
```

I tried various versions of this JQ code, but for id=319 user=foo should have access consume and create, and group=bar should have have access publish and create. But I always end up with both foo and bar having access consume, publish and create (or something else wrong).

I've tried:

```
cat file.json | jq -r '[.[] | select(has("policyItems")) |{"id", "users":(.policyItems[] | .users), "groups":(.policyItems[] | .groups), "access_type":([.policyItems[].accesses[] | .type])} ] '
```

Output:

```
      [
      {
        "id": 319,
        "users": [
          "foo"
        ],
        "groups": [],
        "access_type": [
          "consume",
          "create",
          "publish",
          "create"
        ]
      },
      {
        "id": 319,
        "users": [
          "foo"
        ],
        "groups": [
          "bar"
        ],
        "access_type": [
          "consume",
          "create",
          "publish",
          "create"
        ]
      },
      {
        "id": 319,
        "users": [],
        "groups": [],
        "access_type": [
          "consume",
          "create",
          "publish",
          "create"
        ]
      },
      {
        "id": 319,
        "users": [],
        "groups": [
          "bar"
        ],
        "access_type": [
          "consume",
          "create",
          "publish",
          "create"
        ]
      },
      {
        "id": 320,
        "users": [
          "foo"
        ],
        "groups": [],
        "access_type": [
          "publish",
          "create",
          "consume",
          "create"
        ]
      },
      {
        "id": 320,
        "users": [
          "foo"
        ],
        "groups": [
          "bar"
        ],
        "access_type": [
          "publish",
          "create",
          "consume",
          "create"
        ]
      },
      {
        "id": 320,
        "users": [],
        "groups": [],
        "access_type": [
          "publish",
          "create",
          "consume",
          "create"
        ]
      },
      {
        "id": 320,
        "users": [],
        "groups": [
          "bar"
        ],
        "access_type": [
          "publish",
          "create",
          "consume",
          "create"
        ]
      }
      ]
```

I also tried:

```
cat file.json | jq  ' map({id, "access_type":([.policyItems[].accesses[] | .type])[], "users":(.policyItems[] | .users)[], "groups":(.policyItems[] | .groups)}) '
```

Which provides output:

```
    [
{
    "id": 319,
    "access_type": "consume",
    "users": "foo",
    "groups": []
  },
  {
    "id": 319,
    "access_type": "consume",
    "users": "foo",
    "groups": [
      "public"
    ]
  },
  {
    "id": 319,
    "access_type": "create",
    "users": "foo",
    "groups": []
  },
  {
    "id": 319,
    "access_type": "create",
    "users": "foo",
    "groups": [
      "public"
    ]
  },
  {
    "id": 319,
    "access_type": "publish",
    "users": "foo",
    "groups": []
  },
  {
    "id": 319,
    "access_type": "publish",
    "users": "foo",
    "groups": [
      "public"
    ]
  },
  {
    "id": 319,
    "access_type": "create",
    "users": "foo",
    "groups": []
  },
  {
    "id": 319,
    "access_type": "create",
    "users": "foo",
    "groups": [
      "public"
    ]
  },
  {
    "id": 320,
    "access_type": "publish",
    "users": "foo",
    "groups": []
  },
  {
    "id": 320,
    "access_type": "publish",
    "users": "foo",
    "groups": [
      "public"
    ]
  },
  {
    "id": 320,
    "access_type": "create",
    "users": "foo",
    "groups": []
  },
  {
    "id": 320,
    "access_type": "create",
    "users": "foo",
    "groups": [
      "public"
    ]
  },
  {
    "id": 320,
    "access_type": "consume",
    "users": "foo",
    "groups": []
  },
  {
    "id": 320,
    "access_type": "consume",
    "users": "foo",
    "groups": [
      "public"
    ]
  },
  {
    "id": 320,
    "access_type": "create",
    "users": "foo",
    "groups": []
  },
  {
    "id": 320,
    "access_type": "create",
    "users": "foo",
    "groups": [
      "public"
    ]
    }
    ]
```

Thanks in advance.

**Edit:**
My expected output would be something like this where users and groups are combined and correctly show the correct access.

```
  [
  {
    "id": 319,
    "users_groups": [
      "foo",
      "bar"
    ],
    "access_type": [
      "create"
    ]
  },
  {
    "id": 319,
    "users_groups": [
      "foo"
    ],
    "access_type": [
      "consume"
    ]
  },
  {
    "id": 319,
    "users_groups": ["bar"],
    "access_type": [
      "publish"
    ]
  },
  ...
```

Comment: What is your expected output?

Comment: @hek2mgl - I've added the expected output to the original question. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

I think you want something like this:

```
# Print out your top example input
echo '{"id":319,"policyItems":[{"accesses":[{"type":"consume","isAllowed":true},{"type":"create","isAllowed":true}],"users":["foo"],"groups":[]},{"accesses":[{"type":"publish","isAllowed":true},{"type":"create","isAllowed":true}],"users":[],"groups":["bar"]}]}
{"id":320,"policyItems":[{"accesses":[{"type":"publish","isAllowed":true},{"type":"create","isAllowed":true}],"users":["foo"],"groups":[]},{"accesses":[{"type":"consume","isAllowed":true},{"type":"create","isAllowed":true}],"users":[],"groups":["bar"]}]}' \
| jq -n '[inputs | .id as $id | .policyItems[] | {"id": $id, "access_type": (reduce .accesses[].type as $item ([]; . + [$item])), "users_groups": (.users + .groups)}]'
```

Here's what's happening:

- `echo '{"id":...` We are echoing out your input
- `| jq` Piping that to `jq`
- `jq -n '[inputs | ...]` We accept the echoed input into `jq` as a streaming filter `inputs` (instead of `.`) so that we process the entire input all at once in order to wrap the result in the outer brackets.

  - The `-n` is important here because it instructs `jq` not use piped input implicitly.
- `.id as $id` We save off the parent ID into the `$id` variable for future reference
- `| policyItems[]` We are iterating over the policyItems array, which is what you seem to want to group your results by
- `| {"id": $id, ...` Here we are beginning to construct the results, and referring back to the `$id` we saved off.
- `"access_type": (reduce .accesses[].type as $item ([]; . + [$item])), ...` Here we use the `reduce` filter to combine the access types into a single array
- `"users_groups": (.users + .groups)}` And we finally combine the `"users"` and `"groups"` arrays into one single array

All off this allows us to return an output like:

```
[
  {
    "id": 319,
    "access_type": [
      "consume",
      "create"
    ],
    "users_groups": [
      "foo"
    ]
  },
  {
    "id": 319,
    "access_type": [
      "publish",
      "create"
    ],
    "users_groups": [
      "bar"
    ]
  },
  {
    "id": 320,
    "access_type": [
      "publish",
      "create"
    ],
    "users_groups": [
      "foo"
    ]
  },
  {
    "id": 320,
    "access_type": [
      "consume",
      "create"
    ],
    "users_groups": [
      "bar"
    ]
  }
]
```